# UI completely non-responsive on libreoffice startup

Tags: libreoffice, gui, ubuntu-mate

When starting libreoffice (6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10) on the MATE desktop using a marco window manager, the UI becomes completely unresponsive for quite a while. The mouse pointer can be moved, but does not change based on where it points to, and cannot trigger any UI events. I cannot even switch virtual consoles using Ctrl-Alt-F[1-9].

It seems to be solely related to the local, physical UI. While this happens, the OS is stil very responsive to SSH access. I tried to find an offending process using "top", but there seems to be no major CPU activity. Also, I don't notice any major HDD activity.

Any clues on how to debug this?

Comment: Check the command 'free' before and after starting LO. Perhaps your performance hit is due to swapping.

Comment: @user535733: No, as I wrote there is no major HDD activity, which would also happen if it was swapping.

Comment: Considering that LO development is far beyond 6.0, I would test if the issue persists in a 19.10 or 20.04 LiveUSB session. Maybe somebody already fixed the problem.

Comment: @user535733: As this system is supposed to keep running an LTS release, I tried to upgrade LO using PPA. But it's the same issue with 6.3.5 version I get from PPA.

Comment: @user535733: As this system is supposed to keep running an LTS release, I tried to upgrade LO using PPA. But it's the same issue with 6.3.5 version I get from PPA.